# How to remove mildew from leather shoe

Tags: cleaning, water, shoes

I have a pair of tan leather shoes. Yesterday, I wore them in the rain and let them air-dry over the night. Now there are these white marks on the top of both pairs of shoes.

[image: mildue_on_top]

**Are the marks mildew? how can I get rid of the marks?** I wore these shoes once on a wetter day, and they air-dried without any residues. Next time, how should I dry wet leather shoes?

Also, I realize I haven't taken care of these (expensive) shoes. **How can I restore them to a better condition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems more likely that they are salt marks, and can rather easily be removed by using a combination of water and vinegar. If unsure on how to do this you could do a google search for [remove white marks on tan leather shoe](//google.com/search?q=remove+white+marks+on+tan+leather+shoe). The general procedure is:

- Mix equal parts of white vinegar and water
- Use a clean rag to wipe away the salt. May need to be repeated
- Use another rag with only water to wipe away the vinegar
- Let everything dry again, and hopefully your stain is removed

There are also chemical salt cleaners available for purchase, in which case you would follow the procedure on the product.

Comment: I didn't have vinegar on-hand, so I used rubbing alcohol. It worked. Thanks!